# Im new to Unity and C#, but a lot seems to hinge on understanding this syntax: GetComponent<Renderer>(). Can someone check my understanding?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

`GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;`

meaning:

```
<Renderer> means:
"GetComponent could accept various types, but in this case were sending it a <Renderer> type."
```

Is that close?

If I were to reverse engineer GetComponent, would it start out like:

```
<T> GetComponent(<T> x) { 
    someComponentOfTypeT = someOtherFunction(x);
    return someComponentOfTypeT; 
}
```

Comment: Just read about generics in c#: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetComponent will return a reference to and object if the gameobject had this component attached or null if dont exist

So you can call GetComponent if you want a Rigidbody, AudioSource, Collider, Renderer that is attached to your gameobject. or if you have a Custom script like "ExampleScript" that derive from some other component like MonoBehaviur.

Edit 1:

Your thinking is correct

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check. Its still a bit weird to me to see a class specify a generic (like, public class Compare<SomeType> { ... }). Im ok with seeing it on functions but the class bit is blowing my mind. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a basic c# syntax

This is how it looks like reverse engineered

```cs
public T GetComponent<T>()
{
    var objectWithTypeT = UnitysInternalMethodToGetTheDesiredType();
    return objectWithTypeT;
}
```

I suggest you to check this link [Generic methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods)

The actual method decompiled with JetBrains decompiler

```cs
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public unsafe T GetComponent<T>()
{
    CastHelper<T> castHelper = new CastHelper<T>();
    this.GetComponentFastPath(typeof (T), new IntPtr((void*) &castHelper.onePointerFurtherThanT));
    return castHelper.t;
}
```